# How to Copy contents in a directory to my current directory in shell?

Tags: linux, shell

Let's say I have a directory called A.

Directory A has a bunch of c files, and I want to cp all of these files to the directory the script is running in (in the case it would be Home in the linux system).

To make sure it successfully copied I would then echo whatever was copied.

This is what I have tried:

```
cp -r A Home/  

echo `.c` # prints the files that have a .c at the end after they get copied
```

However the error I am getting is that the directory doesn't exist even though the directory is also in the Home directory. I also tried changing it to another directory which didn't seem to work either.

Another problem is that this doesn't copy to the current directory it copies to home. I used this list to see if there is a shell command, but couldn't find a copy command that allows me to place the files in the directory the script is running in.

https://www-xray.ast.cam.ac.uk/~jss/lecture/computing/notes/out/commands_basic/

Comment: Huh? ```echo `.c` ``` tries to run `.c` as a command, and substitute the output of that command into the arguments for `echo`. Why would you expect it to do anything different?

Comment: ...if you want to list files ending in `.c` without `ls`, use `printf '%s\n' *.c` (better), or `echo *.c` (worse: can't distinguish spaces inside filenames from separators between files), not ```echo `.c` ```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either be in the parent directory of A to copy it somewhere or mention the full path of the files to be copied.

Eg. if B is the parent of A.

You should already be in directory B to execute the command

```
cp -R A <your_destination_folder_path>
```

Eg. cp -R A .
to denote the files are to be copied to the current path

It is better to give the full absolute path of your destination.

If you are already inside of directory A and just want to copy the directory files alone. You can give this

```
cp * <your_destination_folder_path>
```

If you are in any directory but just want to copy the contents of A, then provide the full (absolute) path or relative path to A to copy the files..

Comment: It's absolutely not necessary to be in a directory's parent to be able to copy it -- see my answer demonstrating same.

Comment: Also, see [the POSIX specification for `cp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cp.html): `-r` is no longer specified as part of the standard; `-R` is its newer replacement.

Comment: Yes - I just wanted to check if he was using the command within the directory itself while using the command cp -r A <dest_path> . If he used the full path then it wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Yes I know this but wasn't sure when 'r' and 'R' was used - thanks for specifying the standards :) !!

Comment: Ok, i got rid of the error, but nothing seems to be copied into the current directory:

~$ls
A Desktop Music Home <This is the new directory with the files, but I don't want it to go into a new folder called home, I want them to be copied in the directory the script is running from

Comment: You can use cp -R <directory path where your files are present> .

Comment: Please note that a .(dot) is present to denote the current path at the previous comment

Comment: I apologize for my wording, I meant to say that I want to copy all CONTENTS (files) in the directory to my current directory, so I assume the command would then be:

cp * A . 

?

Comment: @Orcka, no. Passing `-R` makes the `cp` recursive, so just `cp -R A/. .` (as my answer specifies) is enough. In `cp * A .`, the `*` is expanded by your shell to the list of files in your current directory *before* `cp` is started.

Comment: @Orcka, ...or, yes, `cp A/* .` if you don't want to recurse.

Comment: @Orcka You can follow Charles or check if mine works :)

Comment: @Orcka, so, let's say your current directory has files "foo" and "bar", and the subdirectory A has files "baz" and "qux". `cp * A .` would become `cp foo bar A .` *before the shell even invoked it*; the `cp` command then has no way of knowing which of those commands came from the shell's expansion of the `*` and which ones you typed out in full.

Comment: @Pat, ...I'm hoping to teach concepts (so someone can figure out how this works themselves), vs spoon-feeding an answer.

Comment: @Orcka, ...by contrast, in the above example, `cp A/* .` would become `cp A/baz A/qux .`, again, performed by the shell before the executable `/bin/cp`  (or `/usr/bin/cp` or otherwise whatever it is on your OS) is ever started.

Comment: [...that's different from Windows, where wildcard expansion is the responsibility of the command being run rather than the shell that runs it].

Comment: @Orcka please consider choosing he answers helpful if they were :)

Comment: Sorry for the delayed reply, had to fix a leak in my sink. 

The A/* . method almost works perfectly, should have the answer check marked by now.

However there seems to be one last problem, the files are there, but they are not considered c files.

Comment: @Orcka, what do you mean by "considered c files"? How are you testing?

Comment: BTW, I still disagree with the introductory text ("be in the parent directory of A to copy it somewhere or mention the full path of the files to be copied") in this answer, since it falsely implies that relative paths not referring to an immediate child directory (ie. `../somedir/mypath/.`) can't work.

Answer (score 5):

```
cp -R /path/to/other/directory/. .
```

Given on its own (used as a copy destination), `.` refers to the current directory.

Given at the end of a path passed as a source location to `cp -R`, a trailing `/.` indicates that the name of that directory should not be used as a destination element (thus, that we're not copying the directory itself, but its contents).

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward is the following (assuming you are copying a directory and its contents to your current working directory):

cp -R /path/to/dir/ .

The -R means recursively. Notice the space and the dot at the end. That is not a period ending the sentence; that space and dot are instructing operating system to cp the directory and contents of the path specified to your current working directory.